# Add URL in image upload error message

Tags: uploads, media-library

I'm wanting to add a URL link into the image upload error message, but it's only printing the string, not adding the hyperlink.  I'm using the code below

```
  function my_max_image_size( $file ) {
  $size = $file['size'];
  $size = $size / 1024;
  $type = $file['type'];
  $is_image = strpos( $type, 'image' ) !== false;
  $limit = 750;
  $link = '<a href="example.com">';
  $limit_output = '750kb';
  if ( $is_image && $size > $limit ) {
    $file['error'] = 'Image files must be smaller than ' . $limit_output . '<a href="example.com"> Click here to get help</a> ';

// not working either 
 // if ( $is_image && $size > $limit ) {
  //  $file['error'] = 'Image files must be smaller than ' . $limit_output . 'Click here to get help: '.$link.' </a> ';

  }
  return $file;
}
add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'my_max_image_size' );
```

I've also tried with using $var and sprintf, echo, printr but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

It's probable that HTML tags are being removed from output. You can test this by adding other HTML tags (ex: `<strong>`) and see if they are removed. If the bold text shows, it's possible then that bold text is permitted but not links (using `wp_kses()` or similar).

I backtracked the code quite a bit to see if I could find how/where the code was displayed, but did not find it quickly.

If HTML is being stripped in PHP, then the solution is to use JavaScript to add the link in.

Comment: Yes, that's what's happening - hence the reason for the question!

Comment: You will not be able to add the link with PHP then: will need to do some JavaScript manipulation.